# Reintegrate Partially Reverted Changes in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have these branches:

```
//mainline
//branch1
//branch2
```

branch1 is a large set of changes to mainline.

branch2 was created from:

1. Integrated from mainline
2. Integrated from branch1 to get the large changes
3. The files were resolved
4. Many files were reverted because I just wanted a subset of the changes from branch1
5. The changes were submitted
6. Eventually branch2 was integrated back into mainline.
7. branch2 was deleted

Now I need to integrate branch1 into mainline. When I do the integrate in p4v, it misses many of the files because it thinks they were already integrated from branch2 (even though I reverted them). If I "force" integration it thinks every single file (of 8000+) has changed.

**How do I make perforce integrate all the changes in branch1?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the range that you want to integrate, in combination with the "force" integration option. You need to expand the "Limit the range of the integration" section in the Integrate dialog.

[image]

Comment: Even when I specify the revision range, it still changed every single file in the branch.

Comment: @Eric, I misunderstood the situation at first, I took another stab at it.

Comment: branch2 was deleted after it was integrated into mainline :-(

Comment: @Eric Deleted, or obliterated? If it was just deleted, then it's not too hard to bring it back. If it was obliterated, then it's gone for good (unless IT has an old backup, but probably not worth the trouble).

Comment: In the case that it has been obliterated, have you tried running an auto-resolve on the massive forced integration? Depending on how much code churn has happened since the branch was created, and how spread out the changes were, it might not be too terrible after the auto-resolve.

Comment: Your original answer was correct. The key was to exclude the first revision in the branch (branch creation). The first revision was being forced in, so that's why every single file was changed. If you re-revise your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Heh, maybe I shouldn't have second guessed myself :)